# RStudio: Compare two different data tables when row.name is same

Tags: r, match, rstudio, grouping

I have two data frames with different columns and rows:

One of the tables are specifically expressed genes names in rows (750 entries) with statistical analysis (p-val, fold change) in columns. (750x2 matrix)

The second table is all expressed genes names(13,000) and their associated genes in the same row (rows go as long as 100). (13,000x100 matrix)

I am interested in creating a data frame with the 750 expressed gene names from the first file and using a match function in R that will insert the associated genes from table2.

Example:

First Data
table

`Name   Fold Change P-value
A   0   3
B   1   4
F   2   6
H   1   8`

Second Data table

`Name   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
A   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
B   B1  B2  B3  B4  B5
C   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
D   D1  D2  D3  D4  D5
E   E1  E2  E3  E4  E5
F   F1  F2  F3  F4  F5`

Desired Output

`Name   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
A   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
B   B1  B2  B3  B4  B5
D   D1  D2  D3  D4  D5
F   F1  F2  F3  F4  F5`

Comment: be carefull when you write in caps, if feels like you are screaming at us. :)

Comment: Could you please add some example data (doesn't have to be your 13,000 line actual data, you could create smaller dataframes with the same structure). It's easier to understand questions if we can see how your data and code look. See [how to write a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding before. I hope this explains what I need better. Thank you for your time